# Some symbol ॐ is appearing in place of om in string display

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am displaying translated text "Nom" of "Name" in French in Xamarin.Forms Android app. But instead of showing Nom, it shows Nॐ converting characters om into ॐ (om symbol). Could someone help me how to avoid this symbol? I have Googled it with various keywords but couldn't find the solution.

The code I am using to display the text is `<Span Text="{x:Static localization:Localization.Name}" />`.

The resx file code translation is as below.

```
  <data name="Name" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Nom</value>
  </data>
```

About the om symbol: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the font mentioned is FontAwesome instead of LatoFont. That was the root cause of the issue.